# A2DP Bluetooth audio randomly shows "(no media)"

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio, a2dp

Sometimes when I connect my phone to my headset, the Bluetooth device will be listed as:

"**Connected ( no media )**"

[image]

When this happens, it uses the "Phone audio" profile. The "Media audio" profile (A2DP) will also have a checkmark, as if it were connected, but all sound is coming from the phone's speaker (see photo below). If I attempt to uncheck it, it will immediately recheck itself. When it *is* working properly, it will wait two seconds and disconnect.

[image]

Rebooting the headset, or disconnecting it manually doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved: The android system is likely connected to the headset for phone calls, and some **other** device for A2DP (media). Some *other* device is still using the audio connection, even though the sound comes from android's speaker!

What this means is that if you have any *other* A2DP devices that you've paired your android with (laptop/stereo/etc) then **you will have to disconnect via the *other* device, not android.**

However under android's "Paired Devices" list (see image), the *other* device *isn't always listed as connected*, even though it is! If you manually try to un-check the "Media audio" profile for the *other* device, it will *not* disconnect!
You must manually disconnect the *other* device outside of android.

For example: If the *other* device is a laptop, you must disconnect the audio connection using the laptop. If the *other* device has no way to manually disconnect (no buttons), just turn it off and use your android to connect to the correct device.

Comment: Wow, this was my problem and surprising (what a terrible design that you cannot figure it out on the device).  In my case it was a Fedora laptop, which did not show the A2DP device as connected (it was the other day) but as soon as I turned _off_ the Bluetooth stack on the laptop, the "music source" connection was usable _after_ I disconnected and reconnected on Android.

The headset itself said it was "ready to pair" so I don't think it was connected to the laptop.  It may be that since the laptop is paired with the handset as well they were all on the same PAN (needs to be tested/isolated).

Comment: This helped me realize my Android Wear watch was the culprit. I'd just disconnect and reconnect my headphones, and it'd be fine. But I wonder if disallowing "Contact Sharing" to my watch will help...