# No Media profile in Bluetooth connection

Tags: bluetooth, audio, samsung-galaxy-s-5

When I connect my Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0 build G900FXXU1BOC7) to the car (a Hyundai Accent), the Bluetooth connection doesn't show the media profile, only the phone profile. Which is strange, since my previous phone, a Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2), had no problem connecting. The phone profile works fine.

What I've tried:

- Cleared cache and data from the Bluetooth app
- Deleted any music player besides the factory one (poweramp was installed)
- Restarted in safe mode
- deleted all Bluetooth devices in the car and paired the devices again

None of these helped.

I saw [an answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/a2dp-bluetooth-audio-randomly-shows-no-media) that mentions disconnecting other devices, however the car was the first device connected to the phone (as far as I know), and besides deleting the Bluetooth App's data should've solved that problem.

Comment: Apparently it has to do with the car multimedia system not supporting bluetooth media with new Iphones and Androids. It's an AVOX multimedia system, and there's no information about it on the internet, so I'm pretty much dependent on the local representative (switching it is unfortunately not an option).